# How to mask a value from postgresql.log while logging

Tags: postgresql, logging, psql, sensitive-data

I'm in need of masking some sensitive data from logging in postgresql.log

For Example, Let's say I want mask "password@123" from postgresql.log while logging with **"******"**

I tried below configuration,

> log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: REGEXP_REPLACE(%m, ''password@123'', ''******'') '

> log_redact = '(password@123)'

But seems it's not working. Please help me to find a solution

Comment: There is no solution for that. Don't send things to the database that you don't want the database to know.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe We are okay to know to database. Just want to mask in postgresql.log only. Can't we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specifically exclude certain parts of a log message from being logged. Your only option is to disable statement logging completely:

```
log_min_error_statement = panic
log_statement = none
log_min_duration_statement = -1
```